# Is this a right way to use array names for HTML controls?

Tags: html, names, htmlcontrols

Following is my code :

```
<input type="input" name="val['status_info']" id="val['status_info']">
  <input type="input" name="val['group_id']" id="val['group_id']">
  <input type="input" name="val['action']" id="val['action']">
  <input type="input" name="val['is_activity_feed']" id="val['action']">
```

I just want to know is this a correct way of using array keys as names/ids of HTML control?

In other words did I use the single quoted keys into double quoted control names in following scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you need no quotes for the array keys at all.

Comment: And I dont think square brackets are allowed in ids.

Comment: It is permitted in [html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)